# How to identify element in the following code for selenium testing

Tags: selenium

Below is the code snippet :

```
**<input class="el-input__inner" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" placeholder="Identifying Type" autocomplete="off">**
```

How do I identify the placeholder element

Comment: please edit your question, you have missed out a huge part of it

Comment: Add some more details in your code snippet; also paste your code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAttribute()` method to find the placeholder of an element like:

```
String placeholderValue = driver.findElement(By.className("el-input__inner")).getAttribute("placeholder");
```